# In SQL Server, how to SELECT rows that share a common column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my table I have the following values:

```
ProductId  Type      Value      Group
200        Model     Chevy      Chevy
200        Year      1985       Chevy
200        Year      1986       Chevy
200        Model     Ford       Ford
200        Year      1986       Ford
200        Year      1987       Ford
200        Year      1988       Ford
```

In my query, I wanna know if my product is compatible to a certain model in a given year. I'm trying to build a function that returns true or false, depending on the parameters ProductId, Model and Value I pass to it. To be true, the Function have to match both parameters (Model and Year), along with the ProductId in the table, but they must belong to the same group.

For example, if I pass to the function the values 200, Chevy, 1988 it must return False. Notice that the 3 values are found in the table, but they belong to different groups.

On the other hand, if I pass to the function the values 200, Ford, 1986 it must return True, because all 3 values match and belong to the same group.

I think a way of doing that is in multiple steps, like:

1. Select all records that match the model then all that match the year and insert them into a temporary table;
2. Select distinct the groups to another temp table;
3. Loop through each group checking if I find all the matches in that group, returning true when I found or false at the end of the function.

I wonder if there's a better way of doing this in 1 step using only one SELECT command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get both `Model` and `Value` in **one** query, you can join the table on itself:
*(I'll assume that the table is called `products`)*

```
select *
from products as models
inner join products as years 
    on models.productid = years.productid
    and models.group = years.group
where models.type = 'Model' and years.type = 'Year'
```

This will give you rows with `Chevy, 1985`, `Chevy, 1986`, `Ford, 1986` and so on.

Then you just need to put your values (e.g. `200, Ford, 1986`) into the `WHERE` clause.
So the final query for `200, Ford, 1986` will look like this:

```
select *
from products as models
inner join products as years 
    on models.productid = years.productid
    and models.group = years.group
where models.type = 'Model' and years.type = 'Year'
and models.productid = 200
and models.value = 'ford'
and years.value = '1986'
```

Comment: Yes, very clever solution. That will do. Thanks Christian.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overcomplicating it. This should be enough:

```
select exists(select * from Products where ProductId = 200 and Type = 'Year' and Value = 1986 and Group = 'Ford')
```

Comment: The group is irrelevant as parameter. All that matters is the results should belong to the same group. In the example above I want to know if this specific product fits a (Model = Chevy AND Year = 1988), regardless of what group model and year belong to, as long as it's the same group.

Answer (score 0):

How about just a count?

```
select 
    count(*)
from
    products
where
    ProductId = @ProductId and 
    (
        ( Type = 'Model' and Value = @Model ) or
        ( Type = 'Year' and Value = @Year ) or
    )
```

If the count is 2 then you've got a hit.